# How should I read a 9.4GB numpy array without a memory error

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a precomputed numpy array that takes up just under 9.5 GB. I have saved it as both an npy file, and using h5py an hdf5 file. Although I can read this array in, using either format when working interactively with an interpreter, however, when I read it in when actually running a module, I get a "Memory Error":

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/dataset.py", line 440, in __getitem__
    arr = numpy.ndarray(mshape, new_dtype, order='C')
MemoryError
```

This happens whether I save/read an npy file or an hdf5 file.

I have tried using numpy.memmap so I could substitute disk memory for RAM, but do not seem to be able to read the array accurately:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> zz=np.load('VGG16_l19_val.npy')
>>> zz.dtype
dtype('float64')
>>> zz.shape
(50000, 25088)
# So, I've read in the array using np.load and know its dtype and shape

>>> from numpy import unravel_index
>>> unravel_index(zz.argmax(), zz.shape)
(41232, 8208)
>>> zz[41232,8208]
937.5606689453125
# I now know the max value of zz and where it occurs

>>> zz2=np.memmap('VGG16_l19_val.npy', mode = 'r', dtype=np.float64, shape=   (50000,25088))
>>> zz2.dtype
dtype('float64')
>>> zz2.shape
(50000, 25088)
# I've read a memmap version of the array and have the correct dtype and shape, but ...

>>> zz2[41232,8208]
0.0
>>> zz2.max()
memmap(8.447400968892931e+252)
>>>
# It doesn't appear that zz2 == zz
```

What don't I understand about np.memmap? Can I use it to read in this numpy array?

If not, what should I do, other than break up the array and save it in several files?

Why can I read the array without a problem when I'm in the interpreter, or in pdb, but can't read it without a MemoryError when I read it within a module?

Comment: The docs [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) talk about a number of issues `memmap` can have that might apply to your issue

Comment: Not a numpy expert, but looking at the docs it appears you want `numpy.lib.format.open_memmap()`, rather than `numpy.memmap()`.

Comment: Have you explored the `mmap_mode` of `np.load`?

Comment: @glibdud - Thx - this works

Comment: @hpaulj - Thx - this works

Comment: Are you able to get solution to your problem now ?

Comment: @tauseef_CuriousGuy - yes - see the suggestions of glibdud & hpaulj

Comment: @user1245262 You could post a formal answer where you show a minimal concrete example that solves your problem. This could be useful to future readers.